# C# Reflection - how to get interface to pass to a generic method?

Tags: c#, reflection

For unit testing, I am using RhinoMock and in the example below you can see that I successfully create a Stub based on the interface ISomething:

```
var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomething>();
```

All well and good.

However, I'm writing a test which loops through the properties of an object using Reflection and I then want to dynamically create a stub based on the current property.

So, imagine that my class under test is Parent:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ISomething Prop1 {get;set;}
    public ISomethingElse Prop2 {get;set;}
    public ISomethingEntirelyDifferent Prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

With Reflection I can get the individual properties using:

```
typeof(parent).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

And when I iterate through each property, I see the name of the Interface (ISomething, ISomethingElse, ISomethingEntirelyDifferent) on the current property using:

```
p.PropertyType.Name
```

But I'm not sure how to then plug that into:

```
var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<????>();
```

Comment: Isn't there an overload of `GenerateStub` that takes a `Type` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` method.

```
var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
var openGenericMethod = typeof(MockRepository).GetMethod("GenerateStub");
var closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);
var stub = closedGenericMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

When there are multiple `GenerateStub` methods (generic, non generic, ...) you could use `GetMethods()` and then use Linqs `Single` method to find the right one.

**Update**:
After inspection the desired method it turns out the method has a `params object[] objects` parameter. That why you get a `TargetParameterCountException` when invoking with a null value. To solve this you have to pass a wrapped empty object array. This works for me:

```
var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
var openGenericMethod = typeof (MockRepository).GetMethods()
        .Single(x => x.Name == "GenerateStub" && x.IsGenericMethod);
var closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);
var stub = closedGenericMethod.Invoke(null,  new object[] { new object[0] });
```

Comment: I tried using: 
var propertyType = p.PropertyType;
var openGenericMethod = typeof(MockRepository).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.IsEqualTo("GenerateStub")).First(m => m.IsGenericMethod);
var closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);
var stub = closedGenericMethod.Invoke(null, null);

But Invoke gave me a TargetParemeterCountException.

Comment: And in addition, when I then want to use this by having:  var p = new Parent { Prop1 = stub }; I get a compilation error (at least in LinqPad) because the compiler can't implicitly convert "object" to "ISomething"

Comment: Ignore the last comment as I'm sure I could set that using Reflection too.

Comment: Don't use `First` when you expect exactly one result. Use `Single` instead. `TargetParameterCountException` means you got the wrong method. Set a breakpoint in and you will see which method you got.

Comment: The following returns a value of 1, and the breakpoint suggest it's the correct method:  typeof(MockRepository)
  .GetMethods()
  .Where(m => m.Name.IsEqualTo("GenerateStub"))
  .Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod).ToList().Count()

Comment: Ok i found the problem. `GenerateStub` is not a parameterless method, you probably could have seen this while debugging and inspecting the MethodInfo. See my edit.

Comment: Ha - I just had and felt very triumphant, only to find that you'd beaten me to it.  Well done, and many thanks for putting me on the right path!

Comment: No need to pass in an `object` in the parameter array, you can pass in an empty array: `new object [] {}`

Comment: @Jcl No that is not possible, the outer object array will be unwrapped by the `MethodInfo.Invoke` method and the inner empty array will be passed to the method. That is exactly what a method with a *params* parameter expects. When you leave out the inner empty array you will get also a `TargetParameterCountException`. You can verify this need by decompiling a call to a params method with no parameter and you will see that it contains the empty object array as parameter.

Comment: @thehenny I admittedly hadn't tested, but yes, if both methods (Invoke and the target) use `params`, it makes sense